# Javascript and statistics: a library for calculating p-values?

Tags: javascript, statistics, p-value

It seems that there's no library that can calculate p-values with javascript, but how that can be? I'm sure there has to be something.

What I've found is these 2 options that calculate these values but then you should find the code in the web page and adapt to your necessities.

http://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/Business-stat/otherapplets/pvalues.htm#rtdist
http://www.njohnston.ca/2010/09/p-value-calculators-and-graphers-in-javascript/

And a library that also calculates it but without documentation and an abandoned state

https://code.google.com/archive/p/statistics-distributions-js/source/default/source

Is this truth? It doesn't exist any stats js library that has included this calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about https://github.com/jstat/jstat?

I'm not sure they calculate P-values, but I'm sure you can calculate the probabilities you are looking for based on the assumed distribution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, it is the only one that calculates it, so thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As said before, jStat is a great resource.
To help on your search...

Here is the documentation:http://jstat.github.io/all.html

Here is the function that returns pvalues:

```
    jStat.tukeyhsd( arrays )
```

This is what to include in your html

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jstat@latest/dist/jstat.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the github:  https://github.com/jstat/jstat